# CC-BY-NC-ND same as CC-BY-ND-NC?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

When looking at Wikimedia, they say they would forbid certain licenses.
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Licensing#Well-known_licenses

**They list the *CC-BY-NC-ND* and the *CC-BY-ND-NC* licenses seperately.**
Why ? Is there a difference ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a meaningful difference; they just renamed it for version 2.0.  Comparing CC-BY-ND-NC 1.0 and CC-BY-NC-ND 2.0 side-by-side, one can easily see that their scope is the same--there is some rewording, but that rewording is common to all CC-1.0 vs. CC-2.0 licenses, and not indicative of any change in the fundamental scope or purpose of CC-BY-ND-NC vs. CC-BY-NC-ND.